# Is there any way to remove the Redis keys of completed jobs of Horizon?

Tags: laravel, redis

I searched a lot but could not find anything suitable. i found this `Redis::command('flushdb');` but this flush all of my others keys too which will needed to complete queued job.

Comment: are you using Streams?

Comment: what keys do you set before processing jobs ?

Comment: @Ersoy It's set automatically by laravel queue.

Comment: @GuyKorland no!

Comment: @Pusku it is deleted automatically you don’t need to delete it manually.

Comment: @Ersoy Then why is completed and failed jobs are showing in laravel horizon?

Answer (score 0):

Since OP said it is related to `horizon`, it keeps the failed jobs in a the redis under multiple keys.

Get your `HORIZON_PREFIX` from the configuration file; let's say it is `foo`.

You either invoke the following commands in your codebase (tinker maybe)

```
Redis::connection()->del('foo:failed:*'); 
Redis::connection()->del('foo:failed_jobs');
```

Or you can use `redis-cli`

```
127.0.0.1:6379> del foo:failed:* foo:failed_jobs
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379>
```